# What is the best way to save the results of `yarn audit` to a text file?

Tags: yarnpkg

I have tried using [yarn-audit-html](https://github.com/davityavryan/yarn-audit-html) but it outputs a .html file.

I would like the output audit table results from the audit in a text or json file.

Here is the data I am looking for: [image]

Note: copy/paste from the terminal is not an option because of the # of results that are returned.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can redirect the output of `yarn audit` into a file on the command line.

```
yarn audit > audit-output.txt
```

The default output of `audit` contains lots of color sequences that make it difficult to read but could probably be stripped out in post-processing. To get the output as JSON, add the `--json` flag.

```
yarn audit --json > audit-output.json
```

Answer (score 10):

Use this command to output a text file without color codes:

```
yarn audit --groups dependencies --no-color > .yarn-audit
```

Use this command in a build to output text without color and ignore the return code.

```
yarn audit --groups dependencies --no-color > .yarn-audit || true
```

Comment: The second command fails on windows with `':' is not recognized as an internal or external command,`

Comment: @DamianGreen - Change that to true and get the expected results. I've updated my answer to reflect.